# Eclipse - xtend Template

Tags: eclipse, templates, xtend

I tried to create a xtend template from here:
Preferences>Xtend>Templates

```
${imp:import(foo.Bar)}

@Test
def ${name}() throws Exception {
    ${cursor} 
}
```

Even though this is working as Java Template, xtend class will generate following code for this:

```
class Test {
    //Here I pressed Ctrl+Spac
    imp

    @Test
    def name() throws Exception {

    }
}
```

It looks like the syntax I used is not valid in xtend templates. But it doesn't complain any errors too. 
Has anyone tried Xtend templates? please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'import' template variable resolver is not available in Xtend right now. You could file a feature request.